# Security pattern for third party uploads to Azure blob container

Tags: malware, azure, scan

**Scenario**:

- Vendor 1 needs to upload data (.json, compressed .csv files, images and video) to an Azure blob storage container owned by Vendor 2
- Vendor 1 is issued a limited duration SAS token each day to use
- Azure does no scanning of incoming blobs (therefore content is untrusted when it lands)

  - Microsoft recommends [pre-scanning all files before uploading](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/benchmarks/security-control-malware-defense#82-pre-scan-files-to-be-uploaded-to-non-compute-azure-resources)

**Questions**:

- What is a repeatable pattern for Vendor 2 to secure this type of content unpload against malware threats?

Comment: what does "repeatable pattern" mean here?

Comment: Something that can scale to many vendors uploading potentially untrusted content.

Answer (score 1):

> What is a repeatable pattern for Vendor 2 to secure this type of content upload against malware threats?

Assuming you are looking to secure blob from data not uploaded by you. You may use free online service to upload the file temporarily then use virus total like service and call an API to fetch uploaded files from URL and scan for examination by virus total, then parse results after which you may accept the upload of the files with same hashes.(Risk of loss of confidentiality shall be calculated based on how trust worthy those free services are)

OR you may want to have a dedicated server where you upload all the files first then examine them all with other trusted multiple solutions locally installed of your choice then uploading them all at once to blob.

Comment: Can't use free services as you point out, loss of confidentiality. 

Server-direct uploads feel quite risky as well. Especially with multiple vendors and managing directories/permissions/etc. Prefer the SAS token method of uploading directly to Azure Storage.

Looks like it will be quite an automation to move from Storage to VM hosting malware scanner to XYZ. When uploads are in gigabytes, this could take a long time/use a lot of network bandwidth.